# como soluciono un problema con el método fillreport de un jasperfillmanager ? pues este utiliza un nombre de base de datos que no debe ser

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

estoy utilizando: una base de datos tipo **MYSQL**
estoy programando en java - netbeans
y uso librerias de jaspersoft

cómo acceder a los parámetros? que utiliza el método fillreport de un JasperfillManager me refiero a los parámetros de la base de datos. este método parece que utiliza un "new_scheme" como nombre de base de datos pero el nombre de mi base de datos es "biblioteca".

cuando hago click en visualizar la vista previa no hay problemas y el reporte se genera bien pero cuando lo corro el codigo, me surge el problema

me arroja una **excepción:**
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'new_schema.reg_vis' doesn't exist**

el metodo que utilizo es el siguiente:
 JasperPrint jp3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, parametro1, Ventana.cn)

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author WAVE NOISE
 */
public class administrador extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form administrador
 */
static ArrayList<String> carreras = UtileriaWaver.query("carrera", "carrera");
static ArrayList<String> listMix;
static DefaultListModel model;
//parameter for chart(Date1)
static Map parametro1 = new HashMap();

public administrador() {
    initComponents();

    model = new DefaultListModel();
    intitList();
    setLocation(Ventana.p);

    try{
    lista_carreras.setModel(model);
    }catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());}
    //radio buttons for type of chart
    buttonGroup1.add(botonBarras);
    buttonGroup1.add(botonPastel);
    pack();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jDayChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDayChooser();
    jDateChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup3 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jToggleButton_Agregar = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jToggleButton_eliminar1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    lista_carreras = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jToggleButton_make_report = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jDateChooser3 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    jDateChooser4 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    botonBarras = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonPastel = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    botonCuatri = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonSemes = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    allUsers = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    botonespec = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jToggleButton_Agregar.setText("Agregar");
    jToggleButton_Agregar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton_AgregarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jToggleButton_eliminar1.setText("Eliminar");
    jToggleButton_eliminar1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton_eliminar1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lista_carreras.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { " " };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(lista_carreras);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(4, 4, 4)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton_Agregar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 182, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton_eliminar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 285, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton_eliminar1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton_Agregar))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Carreras", jPanel1);

    jToggleButton_make_report.setText("Generar reporte");
    jToggleButton_make_report.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton_make_reportActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Selecciona el rango de fechas");

    jLabel2.setText("Desde");

    jLabel3.setText("Hasta");

    botonBarras.setText("Barras");

    botonPastel.setText("Pastel");

    jLabel4.setText("Tipo de graficos");

    jLabel5.setText("Usuarios");

    botonCuatri.setText("Cuatrimestrales");

    botonSemes.setText("Semestrales");

    allUsers.setText("Todos ");

    botonespec.setText("Motivos especificos");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jDateChooser3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jDateChooser4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jToggleButton_make_report)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(allUsers)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGap(152, 152, 152))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(botonCuatri)
                        .addComponent(botonSemes)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(botonBarras)
                        .addComponent(botonPastel)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(botonespec))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jDateChooser3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jDateChooser4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton_make_report))))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                    .addComponent(botonSemes))
                                .addComponent(botonCuatri)))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                            .addComponent(botonBarras)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(botonPastel)))
                    .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                    .addComponent(allUsers)))
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(botonespec)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Reportes", jPanel2);

    jToggleButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 10)); // NOI18N
    jToggleButton1.setText("Ventana principal");
    jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(186, 186, 186)
            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 481, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 237, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jToggleButton_eliminar1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    int i = -1;
    //confirmacion de eliminacion de carrera
    int confir = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea eliminar esta carrera");
    System.out.println(confir);

    //carrera selecionada
    String carSelect = lista_carreras.getModel().getElementAt(lista_carreras.getSelectedIndex());

    //si realmente esta seguro de eliminar
    if(confir == 0){
    try {
        //index
        i = Integer.valueOf(UtileriaWaver.idCarrera(carSelect));
    } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Elige una carrera a eliminar");
    }
    System.out.println("valor de carrera: " + i);
    if (i != 1) {
        UtileriaWaver.delete("carrera", "carrera", Integer.toString(i));
    } else {
        //solo muestra la carrera a eliminar
        String carrera = "'" + carSelect + "'";
        System.out.println("nombre carrera: " + carrera);

        //obtiene el nombre de carrera mediante el id
        String idcarrera = UtileriaWaver.queryWithCondition("idcarrera", "carrera", "where carrera = " + carrera).get(0);

        //elimina la carrera
        UtileriaWaver.delete("carrera", "carrera", idcarrera);

    }


    //clear the list
    model.clear();

    //I do again query
    carreras = UtileriaWaver.query("carrera", "carrera");

    //update list
    intitList();

    }    
}                                                       

private void jToggleButton_AgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    String newCareer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Agrega tu carrera");
    UtileriaWaver.insert(newCareer, "carrera");

    model.clear();
    //I do again query
    carreras = UtileriaWaver.query("carrera", "carrera");

    //update list
    intitList();
}                                                     

private void jToggleButton_make_reportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
    // evaluará si el rango de fechas es adecuado
    boolean fecha = false;   
    String date2 = "";
    String date1 = "";


    try {
        //obtains the date of the jdatechooser
        int year1 = jDateChooser3.getDate().getYear() + 1900;
        int month1 = jDateChooser3.getDate().getMonth() + 1;
        String day1 = jDateChooser3.getDate().toString().substring(8, 10);

        //The lower value of the range
        date1 = Integer.toString(year1) + "-" + Integer.toString(month1) + "-" + day1;

        //obtains the date of the jdatechooser
        int year2 = jDateChooser4.getDate().getYear() + 1900;
        int month2 = jDateChooser4.getDate().getMonth() + 1;
        String day2 = jDateChooser4.getDate().toString().substring(8, 10);

        //The higher value of the range
         date2 = Integer.toString(year2) + "-" + Integer.toString(month2) + "-" + day2;

        // si la fecha es valida
         fecha = validRangeDate(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2);
         System.out.println(fecha);
    }catch(Exception o){
            System.out.println(o.getCause());
    }
    System.out.println(fecha);

    if (fecha == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La primera fecha debe ser anterior a la segunda fecha por lo menos un dia");
    }

    if (fecha) {
        //reporte para usuarios cuatrimestrales (pastel)
        String routReport = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\ReportQuery.jasper";

        //reporte para usuarios semestrales (pastel)
        String routReport2 = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\ReportQuery_Cua.jasper";

        //reporte de motivos especificados usuarios cuatrimestrales y semestrales (pastel)
        String routReport3;
        routReport3 = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\otros.jasper";

        //reporte de usuarios cuatrimestrales (Barras)
        String repCuaBar = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\barras.jasper";

        //reporte de usuarios semestrales (Barras)
        String repSemBar = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\barras_s.jasper";

        //reporte de todos los usuarios (pastel)
        String repAllUserP = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\reportGeneral.jasper";

        //reporte de todos los usuarios (barras)
        String repAllUserB = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\generalBarras.jasper";

        //reporte de motivos especificados (barras)
        String motEspecB = "C:\\Users\\WAVE NOISE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bibloteca\\src\\Reports\\barras_M_O.jasper";

        //obteniendo las selecciones del los reportes que se crearán
        char barras = botonBarras.isSelected()? 'a': ' ';
        char pastel = botonPastel.isSelected()? 'b': ' ';
        char cuatri = botonCuatri.isSelected()? 'c': ' ';
        char semes  = botonSemes.isSelected()? 'd': ' ';
        char general  = allUsers.isSelected()? 'e': ' ';
        char espec  = botonespec.isSelected()? 'f': ' ';
        //string que se utilizará en un switch
        String verReports = "" + barras + pastel + cuatri + semes + general + espec;

        //secuencia de reportes a mostrar
        System.out.println(verReports);

        switch(verReports){
            case "a cdef":
                showReport(repCuaBar);
                showReport(repSemBar);
                showReport(repAllUserB);
                showReport(motEspecB);
                break;
            case " bcdef":
                showReport(routReport);
                showReport(routReport2);
                showReport(routReport3);
                showReport(repAllUserP);
                break;
        }
    }
}                                                         

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
dispose();       
new Ventana().setVisible(true);
}                                              

/**
 * creará y mostrará el reporte
 * @param routReport especificar la routa del reporte 
 */
static void showReport( String routReport ) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Metodo");
        JasperReport jReport = null;
        System.out.println("Cargando ruta del reporte");
        jReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(routReport);
        //para visualizar el reporte de motivos especificados
        System.out.println("llenando reportes");
  **(aqui falla)------->**      JasperPrint jp3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, parametro1, Ventana.cn);
        System.out.println("Creando frame ");
        JasperViewer jviewer3 = new JasperViewer(jp3, false);
        //Point p = new Point(80, 80);
        //jviewer3.setLocation(p);
        jviewer3.setTitle("Reporte de Motivos especificos");
        System.out.println("visualizando reporte");
        jviewer3.setVisible(true);

    } catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
    }
}

/**
 * inicia la lista de carreras en el cuadro de texto
 */
private void intitList(){
    for (int i = 0; i < carreras.size(); i++) {
        model.add(i, carreras.get(i));
    }
    //System.out.println(mix);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param year1 año de la primera fecha
 * @param month1 mes de la primera fecha
 * @param day dia de la primera fecha
 * @param year2 año de la segunda fecha
 * @param month2 mes de la segunda fecha
 * @param day2 dia de la segunda fecha
 * @return true si la primera fecha es anterior a la segunda 
 */
public static boolean validRangeDate(int year1, int month1, String day, int year2, int month2, String day2 ){
    boolean retorno = false;
   if(year1 <= year2 ){
       if( month1 <= month2  ){
           if(Integer.valueOf(day) < Integer.valueOf(day2) ){
               retorno = true;
           }
       }
   }

    return retorno;
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JRadioButton allUsers;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton botonBarras;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton botonCuatri;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton botonPastel;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton botonSemes;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton botonespec;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup3;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser1;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser3;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser4;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDayChooser jDayChooser1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton_Agregar;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton_eliminar1;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton_make_report;
private javax.swing.JList<String> lista_carreras;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

codigo en java y nombre de la BD[image: reporte generado sin problemas desde el preview]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

excepción:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'new_schema.reg_vis' doesn't exist
class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo. ¡Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! Te recomiendo agregar código y declaracones de tablas en texto en vez de imagenes. Además siempre es útil en casos de excepciónes de compartir la excepción completa y marcar la línea de código propio de que resultó.

Comment: lo haré,  gracias